# Javascript audio file only playing for 2 seconds, then cutting off

Tags: javascript, php, html5-audio

I am retrieving blobs from an SQL database and decoding them in base64, using the blob as the `SRC` attribute.
There is a PHP function to retrieve a blob, which will later be recalled after the current song ends wrapped in a JavaScript function (so that it will be callable again), and a line of code setting the `SRC` for the HTML element as the decoded blob.

The problem is that whenever a song is randomly picked, it plays for a moment, then stops. If i set an ONENDED attribute recalling the function, same happens, only times infinite.
NOTE: no console errors!

Here is the code:

```
function songGenerationJS() {
        let song = document.getElementById("song");

        <?php 
            function generateSong() {
                $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","radio fusionrock");
                $req = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `tracks` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
                $song = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req); 
                $conn->close();                       
            
                return $song;
            }
        $song = generateSong();
    ?>

    song.attributes.src="data:audio/mp3;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($song['Src']);?>"  
    song.play();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the rendered code? That is to say - the code that is visible with CTRL + U once your page loads. If you are worried about copyright issues, you can use a dummy base64 of your mp3 file, instead of a real one.

Comment: Thank you for coming by! Here is the code the Source Inspector shows. Some words are in another language but that should not be a problem.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y6wIQgKJtZTBB6RDGhZWcVAHU8YHbq5O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I believe you can remove the `setInterval` entirely, and just do something like: `melodie.addEventListener("ended",generareCantecJS);` So, not an attribute, but an `eventListener`. Try it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hd4Lnq6/).

Comment: Thank you so much but it gives the same result, even with a button click.  The song reaches its final moment after only 2-3 seconds and then the function is called again...

Comment: Alright, let's try it like this. Is the cut-off problem present in my example as well? Also, does the problem happen [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mej6318d/), too? Does it happen if you try another browser, or a different device (computer, tablet, mobile phone, etc)?

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly but I need my function to autoplay, so I am guessing this is a big part of the problem as well. After a few infernal hours I got the function to change everything in the DOM, except the audio element src. And if it does, it, again, only plays for 2 seconds. It may be the encoding and me using blobs. Would I have to convert blobs into URI's?
I am working in Firefox. Tested it in Chrome and it throws a DOM exception blaming the lack of user interaction.

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, `autoplay` is generally frowned upon, by both Google Chrome (relevant part [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay#new_behaviors)) and Firefox ([relevant part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability)). You might want to check (programmatically) what the current status for autoplay is (the bottom of the linked Chrome docs, and **Example 2** in the linked Firefox docs).